# Return different values of a struct from a function

Tags: c

I want to set a commission for each salesperson in a function that has a dynamic array of struct. If a salesperson sells more than x dollars then you have a commission of 9%, if the person sells less than x then you have a 5% commission.

let us say the size is four, then each person will have 4 separate commission
I want to display four different amounts.

```
double commissionCal(struct Sale *arrSale, int size)
{
    double commission, total;

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        if (arrSale[x].saleAmount > 2000.00)
        {
            commission = arrSale[x].saleAmount * .09; //sets commission
            total = arrSale[x].saleAmount + commission; // adds commission to sale amount

            return total; // I know by adding return total will end the function
        }
        else
        {
            commission = arrSale[x].saleAmount * .05;
            total = arrSale[x].saleAmount + commission;

            return total;
        }
    }


}
```

[image: Console output]

Answer (score 2):

in `c` a function can not return more than one  value by return value.

You have two options here:

option 1: pass a pointer to result variables as parameter that it should receive the outputs

```
void commissionCal(const struct Sale *i_arrSale, int i_size, double * o_total, double *o_commision)
{
  *o_total= 0.;
  *o_commission= 0.;
  // ...
}

// later in your program:
  double total;
  double commission;
  commissionCal(monthlysales, salescount, &total, &commission);
  printf("total: %f commission: %f", total, commission);
```

option 2: define structure and use it as return type

```
struct SaleResults{
  double total;
  double commission;
}

struct SaleResults commissionCal(const struct Sale *i_arrSale, int i_size)
{
  SaleResults results;
  results.total = 0.;
  results.commission = 0.;
  // ...
  return results
}

// later in your program:
  struct SaleResults results = commissionCal(monthlysales, salescount);
  printf("total: %f commission: %f", results.total, results.commission);
```

this option should only be used if your returned data structure is relatively small (just a bunch of values), because a copy is made after return on the assignment to the receiving variable. However modern compiler usually employ return value optimization (RVO) to eliminate this overhead.

Please also note that i changed the sales array input to a `const` pointer.
you should always declare pointer (especially in function parameters) as `const` if your piece of could is not intended to change it.

Comment: When I call my function with printf what type field characters do I use since its a function of struct?

Comment: You cannot directly pass a structure to `printf`, you have to pass basic types. I added `printf`s to the code. if you do not want to store the result in a variable (there is no reason not to do so) then you have to call the function twice like `printf("%d %d\n", commCal(...).total, comCal(..).commission);`